# Why the UDF function doesn't seem when typing it in cell in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a simple UDF in Excel VBA but when typing its name in a cell it doesn't pop up. Why this problem occurs?

**My simple function:**

```
Function NormalVary(ByVal mean As Double, ByVal std As Double) As Double
random = Rnd()
NormalVary = mean + std * random
End Function
```

Comment: Where is the function. It needs to be in a module not in the worksheet code or thiswrokbook code.

Comment: Yes, I have just checked it and it is a workbook code.Now I moved it into a module and it worked. Thanks @ScottCraner.